# Python: Problem with send photo telegram bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I learn to make a telegram bot with python using the `python-bot-telegram` package, but I have trouble with sending photo when I type something, when I try to print, it shows an error that `there is no photo in this request`. sometimes give me an error `Wrong remote file identifier specified: can't unserialize it. wrong last symbol`.

```
starting up bot
https://ews.bmkg.go.id/tews/data/20221005051529.mmi.jpg
there is no photo in this request
```

```
starting up bot
https://ews.bmkg.go.id/tews/data/20221005051529.mmi.jpg
Wrong remote file identifier specified: can't unserialize it. wrong last symbol
```

I'm confused because the print show there is a link as you can see on the log up there, also there is an error when I move the method to `queryHandler` function the error comes like this

```
starting up bot
None
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

script that shows error no photos and wrong file identifier :

```
from telegram import *
from telegram.ext import *
from requests import *


imgUrl=None

def getURl(urlImg):
    imgUrl=urlImg
    print(imgUrl)

def handle_message(update:Update,context:CallbackContext):
    text = str(update.message.text).lower()
    response= r.sample_responses(text)

    update.message.reply_text(response)
    if text == "bmkg" or text == "gempa terkini":
        context.bot.send_photo(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,photo=f"{imgUrl}")
```

but when I change the `photo="https://ews.bmkg.go.id/tews/data/20221005051529.mmi.jpg"` instead `photo = f"{imgUrl}"` it worked

script that shows None error  :

```
from telegram import *
from telegram.ext import *
from requests import *


def handle_message(update:Update,context:CallbackContext):
    text = str(update.message.text).lower()
    response= r.sample_responses(text)

    update.message.reply_text(response)
    if text == "bmkg" or text == "gempa terkini":
        buttons=[
            [InlineKeyboardButton("",callback_data="show_image")],
        ]
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons), text="Tampilkan gambar?")

imgUrl=None

def getURl(urlImg):
    imgUrl=urlImg
    print(imgUrl)

def queryHandler(update:Update,context:CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query.data
    update.callback_query.answer()

    print(imgUrl)

    gempa_di_indonesia = GempaTerkini()
    urlImg= gempa_di_indonesia.get_img()

    if "show_image" in query:
        context.bot.send_photo(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,photo=f"{urlImg}")
```

this is nothing that works, always print None

note: the imgUrl is from an inherited class that returns str

```
def get_img(self) -> str:
        src_img= str(self.result['src'])
        return src_img
```

Am I doing it wrong here?

Comment: Would you mind remove the screenshots of texts from your post and publish the full trace of the error copy pasted and formatted?

Comment: @jlandercy Sure, but I think I've sent a full trace of the error that I try to solve

Comment: No, the traceback is a big blob of text that shows you where the error originated from. It starts with `Traceback (most recent call last):` and ends with a line in the format `<ErrorClass>: <Error message>`.

Comment: thank all I learn a lot, so I figure out that maybe I have to learn about async too because the `imgUrl` is always null

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer to my question, I don't know if I'm right but, I assumed the code run immediately so the `imgUrl` is always `null or None` so I have to learn about async in python

so in this case I have to call from the inheritance class again to get the image URL

```
def handle_message(update:Update,context:CallbackContext):
    text = str(update.message.text).lower()
    response= r.sample_responses(text)

    update.message.reply_text(response)
    if text == "bmkg" or text == "gempa terkini":
        # try:
        #     context.bot.send_photo(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,photo=f"{r.ImgUrl}")
        # except:
        #     traceback.print_exc()

        buttons=[
            [InlineKeyboardButton("",callback_data="show_image")],
        ]
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons), text="Tampilkan gambar?")


def queryHandler(update:Update,context:CallbackContext):
    try:
        query = update.callback_query.data
        update.callback_query.answer()

        ## call it again from inheritance class
        gempa_di_indonesia = GempaTerkini()
        gempa_di_indonesia.run()
        a = gempa_di_indonesia.get_image()

        if "show_image" in query:
            context.bot.send_photo(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,photo=f"{a}")

    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
```